# SalesforceSDKCore Network macros giving build errors in Xcode 9 Beta 3

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios

```
CSFInput.m - NetworkVerbose
CSFInputStreamElement.m - NetworkWarn
CSFAuthRefresh.m – NetworkOAuthDebug, NetworkOAuthInfo
```

The above #define (ex: NetworkOAuthInfo) is in SalesforceSDKCore/Classes/Network/Utilities/CSFInternalDefines.h

Code ex: `NetworkOAuthInfo(@"Initiating auth refresh.");` //when building with Xcode 9 Beta 3 using iOS 11 Beta SDK is returning this error -

> Static Assert failed “format argument must be a string constant”

This is not a problem with Xcode 8 and iOS 10 SDK.

I am not sure when the macro is expanded, where is it failing?  Is it related to `os_log_with_type`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed in Mobile SDK 5.2. See [this Pull Request](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/pull/2053) for more information.